Ubuntu freezes when loading
I had a scary incident the other day. My system crashed after a BSOD. It was so bad that the system re-installed the original Bios. The bios when I bought the motherboard. Yes it was really scarry. Now for the question. Sinds that happened Ubuntu will not boot and will not re-install. It stops after this line "pcie port 0000:05:05:0 : unable to change powerstate from D3hot to D0, device inaccessible ". I waited for about 5 minutes but nothing happens. It does the same when I want to reinstall Ubuntu. The installation holds at the same line. Also the cursor stops blinking and sometimes it just disappears. Do some of you know what has happened ? The motherboard is a AsRock Z390 Phantom Gaming 9. THX.

Did the BSOD happen in Windows or in Ubuntu?

The BSOD happened in Windows. I have Windows 11 installed with secure boot and CSM disabled in the BIOS. TPM was enabled. I had an old hard drive with Windows 8.1 on it and i tryed to format it using the Windows installation disk and then it happened. The system went crazy. Installed the old BIOS 2X. I then removed all the drives exept Windows 11 and cleared the Cmos, because the system kept trurning on over and over again. I turned all the power off and then I could clear the CMOS. Then every thing went OK.

I had to many characters typed. I can not load are install Ubuntu since then. THX for your help.

Sorry it took so long to react but I had troubles to log in Ubuntu.com.

It would be handy if Ubuntu send me an e-mail that someone post a reaction to my question.

Sorry, there is no such feature in Ask Ubuntu. You will have to login and check periodically

Is everything OK now? Then please add what you did as an answer in the textbox below, so that it can help future users.
